# Не работает слайдер(карусель)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, slider

Добрый день! Подскажите, в чем проблема? [Здесь все работает](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/xSLrD/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xSLrD),
а в моем случае не работает:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel();
$('#myModal').modal()
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display: block;" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
            <li class="" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" active>
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/900x500/666/">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                <p>First slide Caption.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/900x500/666/">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                <p>Second slide Caption.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
              <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/900x500/666/">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                <p>Third slide Caption.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Controls --><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-generic"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!--BEGIN-INTRO-BOX-->
```

Comment: Jquery подключили ?

Comment: <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Даниил, Подключил, все равно не работает

Comment: Сделайте структуру как на странице "Basic template" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ Между body вставьте ваш код.

Comment: @Даниил, выдает вот что: 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
dsdsds.html:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at dsdsds.html:20

Comment: Jquery должен быть подключён выше всех  прочих скриптов

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте чтобы ваш код заработал подключите библиотеку [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) в ваш проект **до того** как подключаете bootstrap.min.js. Желательно скачайте себе Bootstrap .css & .js и также подключите их со своего компьютера (сервера).**bootstrap.min.js добавляйте в конце файла.**

```
<script 
src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--Добавьте это!!-->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<--Конец-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: делал все как сказали, все равно не работает,дело в том что ц меня в head stylesheet а внизу все script-ы ,может быть из за этого?

Comment: [я вывел сюда все подключения,может кто посмотрит укажет мне на ошибку](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwxjKq)

Comment: [Полный код](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwGBmo)

Comment: У вас есть этот код локально (на компьютере)?

Comment: ,да на компьютере есть

Comment: Смысл в том что вы должны в тот код что у вас подключить jquery, самое основное до того как подключён bootstrap (выше) и всё сработает.

Comment: Вот [код скопируйте так всё работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oub14Lkh/)

Comment: [вот что получается](https://codepen.io/sergei174/pen/EbPXPJ)

Comment: Как видите это проблема не того кода что я вам дал (там ведь всё работает). Поэтому нужно искать проблему в остольном коде скорее всего где то что-то не подгружаеться из-за неправильно подключённых внешних файлов

Comment: Сделал как сказали, он работает, но не отображает, просто белая область, это тоже проблема с сылками?

Comment: Покажите, я незнаю

Comment: [вот здесь полный код](https://codepen.io/sergei174/pen/qVbgXJ)